# Feed the beast does not load latest MC version

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

So i had two versions of minecraft on my system. I overwritten one minecraft.exe since i had to manually download 1.6, at least it said so on the main minecraft screen. Then i downloaded feed the beast, copied it to the new folder and ran it for the first time. I had a bunch of yellow warnings and red errors in the log but it started minecraft eventually. But the older version 1.5x.

I deleted the .minecraft folder in the appdata and both the regular minecraft maps. Searched the registry for any minecraft related, installed the latest MC (which loads 1.6). Then did the same with feed the beast, chose the same installation folder as the new minecraft folder and let it run again. Eventually i got MC 1.5x running again instead of the latest.

Does feed the beast only work with 1.5x, or is there something wrong? I have seen a youtube video and they had a funky menu on the main screen that i do not have. I have the feeling something is wrong but i can not put my finger on it.

Comment: Related: [Why does tekkit not update to the newest version of minecraft?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/109193/why-does-tekkit-not-update-to-the-newest-version-of-minecraft)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feed the Beast is a collection of mods, and mods have to be for specific version of Minecraft. In this case, FTB is a collection of mods for 1.5, as a 1.6 edition of FTB has not yet been created.

The "funky menu" you've seen in some videos is from FTB for Minecraft 1.4.7: that's the VoxelMenu mod, which had not been updated to 1.5 yet when this edition of FTB was created and therefore wasn't included.

In other words, FTB is working correctly.

(Also note that Minecraft does not use the Windows registry.)

Comment: What about the couple dozens of errors and warnings?

Comment: @MennoGouw Oh, those are normal. Mods are not the best examples of programming. Java has a try-catch programming model; a lot of those errors are the code trying to do something just to see if it can, and the scary-looking error messages are just the modder not covering up the failed try with a nicely-formatted output catch. For example, a mod might say, "Is there an updated version of me? Let's try to download it anyway... **java.io.FileNotFoundException: [piles of stacktrace]** Oh, I guess not! That's okay, moving along..."

Comment: technically FTB is a collection of modpacks which each are a collection of mods, each modpack requires a specific MC version to run, there are packs targeting 1.2.5, 1.4 and 1.5